# How could you generate test data with no input data in SAS?

Tags: sas

How to generate test data with no input data in  SAS?

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? What worked and what didn't work in your tests? How should the data be structured? How much data?

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Answer (score 4):

## Why don't you use one of the example datasets in the SASHELP library?

For instance

```
proc print data=help.class;
run;
```

[More examples can be found here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_sashelp_sect001.htm)

## Another alternative is to use inline data,

like in

```
data person;
   infile datalines delimiter=','; 
   input name $ dept $;
   datalines;                      
John,Sales
Mary,Acctng
;
run;
```

## If you realy want to use no input at all, use a data step with a loop.

like in

```
data whatever;
   do Key = -99 to 99 by 2;
      Square= Key*Key;
      Value= rand("Uniform"); 
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the `sashelp` library, but if you are looking for something different - check out the Bizarro Ball data here: https://github.com/allanbowe/BizarroBall

To import, just run the following:

```
filename bizarro url 
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/allanbowe/BizarroBall/master/bizarroball.sas";
%inc bizarro;
```